# Android showing dialog on top of another dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I have an application which will show notifications in a dialog window. When a dialog is open and before I tap on the ok button, I got another notification which will show it on the top. Now if I press the ok button on the second dialog, it will navigate to the next page, also it will throw the error

```
02-22 17:34:49.493 17033-17033/com.gadgeon.ulch E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity AlertDialogActivity has leaked window DecorView@2ba2fae[] that was originally added here
```

Could someone please help me to avoid this error and also how to show the first alert, in the new page

Comment: You could dismiss the first one with dialog.dismiss(); where `dialog` is your original AlertDialog.Builder dialog

Comment: Would like to see your code which caused that error

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is extend a DialogFragment and have a viewPager inside of that.  Then as notifications come in you can add them to your viewPager with navigation mechanisms you could provide.